# How to find IP address of my other Mac?

Tags: bonjour, network

I have two Macs on the same network, both plugged into my internet router.  I have screen-sharing set up on one of them, so I can connect to it using command-K in the Finder with a `vnc://` URL, and that works great.

My router assigns IP addresses using DHCP, which in general is a good thing, but it means if a machine gets restarted or a DHCP lease gets renewed, I don't know what IP address to connect to (without walking over to the other machine to find out).

Surely my Mac already knows the IP address of my other Mac: in the Finder, I can see my other Mac's name and icon/type in the sidebar!  Unfortunately, Get Info doesn't display the IP address, or anything else useful about it.

How can I find out the IP address of my other Mac, perhaps using Zeroconf/Bonjour?  I'm fine with a command-line solution, if there's a simple one.

EDIT: I'm running Lion, and I think that OS X screen sharing broadcasts a Bonjour service announcement for it, but Lion's connect-to-server dialog box doesn't take advantage of it.  If this is something Mountain Lion does, knowing that would be helpful, too!

Comment: Ping its network name and it will return its IP. (E.g. `ping other-computer’s-name`)

Comment: Alex: Yeah, but the problem is how to get its hostname, if I only know its Zeroconf broadcast name (which is not the same).

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Your computers should be accessible as **computer-name.local**, e.g. **Kens-Computer.local** or something like that, so depending on what you're trying to do, you might be able to just use that name rather than the IP.

So you can just type **vnc://Kens-Computer.local** in the 'Connect to' window. You can see the computer's network name if you go to the **Sharing** preference pane in **System Preferences**. It's at the top of the page, with a message like "*Computers on your local network can access your computer at: Kens-Computer.local*"

Make sure you include the ".local" suffix to get the Bonjour IP, otherwise your DNS look-up might auto-append some other hostname suffix (depending on your network/DHCP configuration) or simply fail to find the right host.

If you really want to get the IP though, here's a couple of options:

#### Bonjour / dns-sd

You can use Bonjour directly via commands like the DNS Service Discovery tool (dns-sd). Try the following in the Terminal application:

```
% dns-sd -q computer-name
DATE: ---Tue 09 Oct 2012---
18:13:39.209  ...STARTING...
Timestamp     A/R Flags if Name                             T   C Rdata
18:13:39.210  Add     2  4 Computer-Name.local.             1   1 10.1.1.141
```

The `dns-sd` tool can do quite a bit, e.g. if you want to list all local VNC services (at least the ones advertised via Bonjour). VNC services are advertised as "_rfb" in mDNS/Bonjour:

```
% dns-sd -B _rfb local
```

#### Ping

Or you can just ping it, which will show the IP in the output (and is just using Bonjour/mDNS to find the IP).

```
% ping computer-name.local
PING computer-name.local (10.1.1.141): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 10.1.1.141: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.066 ms
```

Comment: This is a fairly complete answer, and helped me figure it out.  The missing piece of the puzzle was that I need to go to the Sharing control panel on that Mac to find out exactly what it thinks the name is -- it replaces spaces and non-Latin characters, so the "name" I see in the Finder, or from `dns-sd`, isn't the "name" I need to use with `ping` or a `vnc://` URL.  I haven't found a way to figure this out from over the network yet, which is strange.

Comment: @Ken: I had the same problem.  Try looking at the zone file output and the `SRV` record.  I found that using service type `_rfb` worked well to display all the macs with screen sharing enabled on my network.  Try: `dns-sd -Z _rfb` or `dns-sd -Z _rfb local | grep SRV`

Answer (score 11):

Open Terminal and type: `arp -a` it will list all the computers on the network and (usually) the host names.

Comment: This command displays 4 entries for me -- my cable modem, my router, my wifi base station, and the strange entry "? (192.168.15.255) at ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff" -- but not my other Mac.

Comment: The 255 address is the subnet mask. Try doing `ping -c5 192.168.15.255` then running `arp -a`.

Answer (score 2):

You can login to the router and look for *DHCP Table*. It will list all connected devices along with their MAC and IP addresses.

But to avoid this issue altogether, why don't you setup *DHCP Reservations* through your router? Through that, you can assign a certain MAC address to a specific IP. That way your DHCP IPs remain constant.

The steps necessary to achieve that will depend on the router brand and model.

Comment: My router doesn't support DHCP static leases, and even if it did, I don't think I'd want that.  I consider it a feature that I don't need any special config for any of my networking hardware, so I can do a "reset all" if it goes crazy (or replace it with a new one).  I have enough to keep track of!

Answer (score 1):

An alternative is you can log into your router on your browser to see the devices on the network and their IP address.  On my linksys, I go to 192.168.1.1, click on status then local network and then DHCP Client table.  It shows every device on the network and it's IP address.

You can see your **router IP** if you check your IP settings, as it will be stated as **DHCP**-**Server** or **Router**.

Answer (score 1):

`arp -a` should give you all the devices within your network.

From `man arp`:

> arp -- address resolution display and control
>
> The arp utility displays and modifies the Internet-to-Ethernet address
>        translation tables used by the address resolution protocol (arp(4)).
>        With no flags, the program displays the current ARP entry for hostname.
>        The host may be specified by name or by number, using Internet dot nota-
>        tion.
>
> -a      The program displays or deletes all of the current ARP entries.

Answer (score 0):

To find ip address on MAC , follow the below steps :

1. Launch the Terminal located in /Applications/Utilities/
2. Type the following command:

   ```
   ifconfig |grep inet.*broadcast
   ```

If you want to find an external ip address visit http://www.ip-details.com/ or http://www.whatismyip.com/.

Answer (score 0):

Head to `System Preferences > Sharing` and check your `Local Hostname`.

This should be something like `Mac-Mini.local`. You can use this instead of an IP to reference the computer on your network.

Safari address bar will take an address and port such as: `Mac-Mini.local:8080`

Comment: But what if one cannot/ doesn't want to open Mac-mini, which I feel is the question aims to do here

Comment: @ankii Fair, but I was searching for "how to find Mac IP" etc. because I thought that was the only option. I think a lot of people might prefer finding their `Local-Hostname.local` *once*, then use it going forward.