# Find IP address of ethernet printer when Location is “Home”

Tags: network, printing, ethernet

I want to find the IP address of my home ethernet printer. When I follow instructions like here:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rGK3DUbFz2c
in both cases, it says that the Location is Home. How do I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A sure fire way to find the IP address of your printer (any device for that matter) is to ping the broadcast address.

1. Get your broadcast address:

   ```
   ifconfig en0 | grep broadcast | awk '{ print $6 }'
   ```

   Use `en0` for wired ethernet and `en1` if you are on wireless.  You will get output similar to the following:

   ```
    192.168.1.255
   ```
2. Ping the broadcast address

   ```
   ping 192.168.1.255
   ```

   Let it run for about 30 seconds or so....Then hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>  to stop it.

   Alternatively, you can specify the time by adding it to the ping command:

   ```
   ping -t 30 192.168.1.255
   ```
3. Type `arp -a` and look for your printer.  You will get output similar to what's shown below (IPs have been changed for security).

   ```
   router.home (192.168.1.1) at 0:1b:21:c4:c5:55 on en0 ifscope [ethernet]
   ? (192.168.1.4) at 0:4:b:b4:6b:d8 on en0 ifscope [ethernet]
   unifi.home (192.168.1.18) at 80:2a:a8:40:f0:21 on en0 ifscope  [ethernet]
   cp2025dn.home (192.168.1.25) at 78:e3:b5:f6:5f:13 on en0 ifscope [ethernet]
   lex.home (192.168.1.55) at 0:21:b7:10:38:3b on en0 ifscope [ethernet]
   allans-mbp.home (192.168.1.13) at 0:26:b0:e8:bb:a6 on en0 ifscope [ethernet]
   brwc48e8f209375.home (192.168.1.110) at c4:8e:8f:20:93:75 on en0 ifscope [ethernet]
   ipad-5.home (192.168.1.115) at b0:34:95:21:68:5b on en0 ifscope [ethernet]
   allans-iphone.home (192.168.1.126) at (incomplete) on en0 ifscope [ethernet]
   allans-imac.home (192.168.1.123) at a8:20:66:39:2c:1c on en0 ifscope permanent [ethernet]
   diskstation.home (192.168.1.221) at 0:11:32:15:da:4c on en0 ifscope [ethernet]
   plex.home (192.168.1.235) at (incomplete) on en0 ifscope [ethernet]
   ```

In my case, I have two  printers on my network - my HP CP2025dn and a Lexmark E260 with DNS/IPs as cp2025dn.home/192.168.1.25 and lex.home/192.168.1.55 respectively.

As for the "Location" field, this is something that is set up by the user or Sys Admin.  In my case, it's getting the information directly from the printer.  See printer Setting page below for my Lexmark printer.  What you saw in the YouTube video is misleading because the IP address had to be manually populated in this field.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

1. Open System Information.app
   (from the /Applications/Utilities folder, or Apple menu → About This Mac → System Report).
2. Choose Printers from the Hardware section, then select your printer.
3. Inspect the IP from the URI. See the highlighted green area in the screenshot.

   [image]

The ‘tutorial’ YouTube video is completely incorrect. The ‘Location’ shown in the video is simply a text field where one can type any information they like.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. In the URI field, it does not have an ip address. Instead it has this: `dnsdd://Dell%20Laser%20Printer%20n._printer._tcp.local./`. I don't see an ip address in any other of the fields either.

Comment: @AlLelopath In that case your Mac is not communicating to your printer using its IP address, but rather your Mac looks for the hostname on the network. You may be able to look up the IP address given this using the `dns-sd` command, see [How can I list the IP addresses of all the AirPrint printers on a network?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/175241/37797).

Comment: `dns: command not found`  Hmph.

Comment: @AlL The command is `dns-sd`.

Comment: Sorry, I thought -sd was a parameter to the command dns. Even so, I don't see an ip address. So question for what I do see.

Comment: @AlL See the link mentioned, there’s more to it than just running the command with no options.

Answer (score 1):

My first try it's usually to retrieve that information from the printer by going to the "printer web page":

- open "System Preferences" from the Apple menu
- choose the "Printers & Scanners" panel
- choose your printer from the list, it should be online (green dot) even if idle

  then
- click the "Options & Supplies..." button
- click on the "Show Printer Webpage..." button

  or
- click on the "Open Print Queue..." button
- select "Settings" from the "Printer" menu (or CMD+S)
- click on the "Show Printer Webpage..." button

  usually the printer web page contains also the network information (as usually does also the test page - you can print it from the Queue window)