# How can I lookup the IP address of a Bonjour host?

Tags: macos, network, dns, bonjour

Normally, if I want to point to a Bonjour-capable host on my local network, I can use its local network hostname, `hostname.local`, as in:

```
$ ssh pi@raspberrypi.local
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work for all programs. I get DNS lookup errors when I try this notation in Cyberduck, for example.

[image: Cyberduck's DNS lookup error]

So I tried the usual ways of looking up hostnames so I could just type in its IP address. First try, thanks to muscle memory was `whois`:

```
$ whois raspberrypi.local
% IANA WHOIS server
% for more information on IANA, visit http://www.iana.org
% This query returned 0 objects.
%
% You queried for raspberrypi.local but this server does not have
% any data for raspberrypi.local.
```

Duh. Of course this of course didn't work because the Internet has no idea who my local machine is. I tried some more:

```
$ nslookup raspberrypi.local
Server:     1.1.1.1
Address:    1.1.1.1#53

** server can't find raspberrypi.local: NXDOMAIN
host -a raspberrypi.local
Trying "raspberrypi.local"
Host raspberrypi.local not found: 4(NOTIMP)
```

Oops. That's also asking the Internet. How about…

```
$ host -t NS raspberrypi.local
Host raspberrypi.local not found: 3(NXDOMAIN)
```

Still no luck. Help me out folks, how can I lookup the IP address of another machine on my local network if all I know is its Bonjour hostname?

---

**Update:** Apparently, Cyberduck gives the misleading DNS lookup error if you accidentally type the username into the *Server* field, as in `pi@raspberrypi.local` instead of `raspberrypi.local`. ‍♂️ It's still a valid question, but not a great premise.

Answer (score 7):

## Use `dns-sd`

It's the Multicast DNS (mDNS) & DNS Service Discovery (DNS-SD) tool for BSD.

```
$ dns-sd -Gv4v6 <hostname>.local
```

For my example, I write:

```
$ dns-sd -Gv4v6 raspberrypi.local
```

And get the IP (redacted) in the address column:

```
DATE: ---Wed 19 Jun 2019---
14:23:40.213  ...STARTING...
Timestamp     A/R    Flags if Hostname               Address         TTL
14:23:40.531  Add        2  5 raspberrypi.local.     <redacted MAC>  120
14:23:40.548  Add        2  5 raspberrypi.local.     10.1.2.3        120
14:23:40.838  Add        3  5 raspberrypi.local.     <redacted MAC>  120
14:23:40.838  Add        2  5 raspberrypi.local.     10.1.2.4        120
```

Hostnames and IP addresses have been changed to protect the innocent. I found this answer by looking for [other questions](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/175241/how-can-i-list-the-ip-addresses-of-all-the-airprint-printers-on-a-network) about finding Bonjour machines.

Comment: Where is the IP address? At least put in 192.1.2.3 or some non routable address to show how the answer gives an IP address resolution.

Comment: Are the `<redacted local IP>` and `<redacted MAC>` insufficient?
Update: changed the `redacted` tags to false IP addresses.

Comment: That looks awesome! On mobile I didn’t see it was scrolled content so it looked horribly short.